# Is there any way I can use index inside a cy.get('k")?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, html-table, cypress

I have a table-like structure where each cell takes some input. The html tag has id something like `id="code[0].name"`, `id="code[0].age"`, `...`, and so on. Similarly, `id="code[1].name"`, `id="code[1].age"`, `...`, and so on

Now, in cypress, I want to perform something like this,

```
namesToFetch.forEach( (el,k) => {
   cy.get('[id=code[k].name]').type(name)
```

My question is, how to use the k'th index inside the `cy.get()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```js
namesToFetch.forEach( (el,k) => {
   cy.get(`[id=code[${k}].name]`).type(name)
```

Or, you could use:

```js
namesToFetch.forEach( (el,k) => {
   cy.get('[id=code[' + k + '].name]').type(name)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can wild-card the matching selector

```js
cy.get('input[id$="name"]')  // elements with id attribute ENDING WITH name
  .each(($el,idx) => {
    cy.wrap($el).type(namesToFetch[idx])
  })
```